# Editing the Descriptive Statistics in SPSS Histogram

Tags: spss

With SPSS v.25, I'm trying to add (via syntax) descriptive text a histogram's descriptive stats. So in the area of the graph that shows the Mean, Std. Dev, and N, is there a way to add text (again, via syntax)? Here's where I'm at:

```
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=TS_Pre_Raw_Sq_21 TS_Post_Raw_Sq_22   MISSING=LISTWISE 
    REPORTMISSING=NO
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: TS_Pre_Raw_Sq_21=col(source(s), name("TS_Pre_Raw_Sq_21"))
  DATA: TS_Post_Raw_Sq_22=col(source(s), name("TS_Post_Raw_Sq_22"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Team STEPPS Pre-Test Raw Score 2018 Fall"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Frequency"))
  GUIDE: text.title(label("Team STEPPS Analysis"))
  GUIDE: text.subtitle(label("Insert Term Here; e.g, Fall 2018"))
  GUIDE: text.subsubtitle(label("Insert Cohort"))
  GUIDE: text.footnote(label("Pre Test: Green Post Test: Blue"))
 GUIDE: legend(aesthetic(aesthetic.color), label("Gender"))
  ELEMENT: interval(position(summary.count(bin.rect(TS_Pre_Raw_Sq_21))), 
    shape.interior(shape.square), color(color.green), transparency.interior(Transparency. "0.6")))
  ELEMENT: interval(position(summary.count(bin.rect(TS_Post_Raw_Sq_22))), 
    shape.interior(shape.square)), color(color.blue), transparency.interior(Transparency. "0.8")))
  ELEMENT: line(position(density.normal(TS_Pre_Raw_Sq_21)))
  ELEMENT: line(position(density.normal(TS_Post_Raw_Sq_22)))
END GPL.
```

And this is what I get:
[image: SPSS Histogram]

So I have forced distributions from two variables in the graph but the descriptive stats aren't labeled; I'd like to add be able to show which stats correspond to which distributions.

Thanks in advance!